# What is on my dryer vent cover?

Tags: dryer

I have a gas Speed Queen dryer and something keeps accumulating on the heat duct vent cover.  I've replaced the cover once thinking something melted on it, but it's happened again.

Other than the melted gunk sometimes getting on clothes,  there's no damage to any of the clothes we put in the dryer.

Any ideas what's causing this?

[image: Pic 1]   [image: Pic 2]

Comment: probably the stuff in the dryer sheets or in fabric softener ... could also be the plastic micro fibers that clothes shed

Comment: Strange! The shape also. The opacity appears more solid top-right, in the square corner and appears to spray diagonally. It's as if it's coming from behind in the corner

Comment: @Chris SO rotated the pic for some reason.  The "90 degree" angle is actually toward the middle of the dryer.

Comment: Appliance usage questions are off topic here. Sorry.

Comment: @isherwood Apologies.  What's the correct exchange site?

Comment: I would run it empty a few times after cleaning, see if you get it reappearing. May help with origin

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know of a good "stack" for this sort of question. That said, it would be interesting to know if the "material" was only on the outside of the grille; perhaps the flame isn't burning cleanly, and is making it all the way up to the grill and causing the cloth fibers to melt.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about appliance service.

Answer (score 1):

The dark mark is a substance that melted from the heat. The unidentified mark appears to be a plastic material (at least in my opinion). This could be anything from a candy or cigarette wrapper to ziplock baggie.

Most likely it was in some ones pocket and went unnoticed after washing. If there is still a film remaining it would be wise to scrape it off so it doesn't transfer to any brilliant whites clothing in future dryer usage.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably drying something that shouldn't be heat dried but only air fluffed.  Spandex, rubber shoes, sandals, certain gym clothes just to name a few.